# $ z^m + z^{-m}$ if $z^1 + z ^{-1} = 2\cos\phi $

Tags: complex-numbers

I have to solve the following equation,

> Calculate $z^m + z^{-m}$, if $ z^1 + z^{-1} = 2  \cos\phi$

Could someone provide an insight or hint how can I solve this ?

Comment: Try checking out De Moivre's theorem. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Moivre's_formula

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since$$0=z^2-(e^{i\phi}+e^{-i\phi})z+1=(z-e^{i\phi})(z-e^{-i\phi})\implies z=e^{\pm i\phi},$$each root gives $z^m+z^{-m}=\sum_\pm e^{\pm im\phi}=2\cos m\phi.$

Comment: Could you please explain how and why  $z^m + z^{-m} = \sum_\pm e^{\pm im\phi} = 2cosm\phi$ ?

Comment: @RustemSadykov If $z=e^{\pm i\phi}$, $z^m=e^{\pm im\phi}$ while  $z^{-m}=e^{\mp im\phi}$. Each choice for signs gives $z^m,\,z^{-m}$ as a permutation of $e^{im\phi},\,e^{i-m\phi}$.

Answer (score 0):

$$z+1/z=2 \cos t \implies z^2-2\cos t+1=0 $$ $$\implies z=\frac{2\cos t\pm 2\sqrt{\cos^2 t-1}}{2} =\cos t\pm i \sin t\implies z=e^{\pm it}.$$
So, $$z^m+z^{-m}= e^{\pm i mt}+ e^{\mp i mt}$$ $$=\cos mt \pm i\sin mt+ \cos mt \mp i \sin mt=2 \cos mt$$